# shell script at ssh login screen

Tags: ssh, motd

I want to run this command when there is an ssh login.

The command is

`watch -n 5 'zen-cli getinfo | grep blocks'`

I have already added this line by doing this
`sudo crontab -e`

I added `@reboot watch -n 5 'zen-cli getinfo | grep blocks'` in crontab

But it does not solve my problem. I want to show this specefic output at the startup screen when there is ssh login like the following:

```
    Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.154-1124-rockchip-ayufan-ged3ce4d15ec1 aarch64)
                _                     __   _  _   
 _ __ ___   ___| | ___ __  _ __ ___  / /_ | || |  
| '__/ _ \ / __| |/ / '_ \| '__/ _ \| '_ \| || |_ 
| | | (_) | (__|   <| |_) | | | (_) | (_) |__   _|
|_|  \___/ \___|_|\_\ .__/|_|  \___/ \___/   |_|  
                    |_|                           

 * Documentation:  
 * Management:     
 * Support:        

  System information as of Wed Dec  5 06:58:25 UTC 2018

  System load:  0.28               Processes:           163
  Usage of /:   24.1% of 58.39GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 26%                IP address for eth0: 192.168.100.82
  Swap usage:   0%


 * MicroK8s is Kubernetes in a snap. Made by devs for devs.
   One quick install on a workstation, VM, or appliance.
Current zen blocks are synced at
```

When I run my `sh code` it returns

```
rock64@rockpro64:/etc/update-motd.d$ sh 90-figlet 
+ zen-cli getinfo
+ grep blocks
+ printf Current zen blocks are synced at  "blocks": 424064,
```

but when I exit and login again, at login it shows this `Current zen blocks are synced at <blank>`

This is my `sh code`

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
printf "Current zen blocks are synced at  $(zen-cli getinfo | grep blocks)"
```

Comment: Watch is a command that doesn't terminate on its own. Do you want the account to be unable to do anything on the machine (other than seeing the output of `watch`)?

Comment: I do not need ```watch``` i think, I just use it manually for convenience.
I am doing some memory intensive work on this device and ```watch``` is not the primary function, just need it to make things convenient so that the users do not have to run ```zen-cli getinfo | grep blocks``` every-time they log in. and also to make sure that the server is running

Comment: Seeing as you're running ubuntu, just put your script in /etc/update-motd.d/  ... ?

Comment: I tried that, but it does not work

Comment: Did you make the script executable with `chmod +x`? Also, you probably want to remove that entry from the crontab. It tells the system to run the watch command on Boot, but it doesn't print its output anywhere as there is no session (it's useless).

Comment: When I run my ```sh code``` it returns 
```rock64@rockpro64:/etc/update-motd.d$ sh 90-figlet 
+ zen-cli getinfo
+ grep blocks
+ printf Current zen blocks are synced at  "blocks": 424064,
```
but when I exit and login again, at login it shows this ```Current zen blocks are synced at <blank>```

This is my code


`#!/bin/sh
set -x
printf "Current zen blocks are synced at " $(zen-cli getinfo | grep blocks)`

Comment: Does it show you the literal string `<blank>`, or do you mean that there's just a blank space (ie. the line ends after `...synced at`)?

Comment: Apologies for making you confused, I meant the line ends after ```....synced at```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the environment not being fully initialized.

The following works for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
# set -x

blocks=`sudo zen-cli getinfo | grep \"blocks\"`

printf "\n"
printf "Current zen blocks are synced at  $blocks\n"
```

Comment: I have just tried it but did not work. It is strange because when I run ```run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/``` it works, but when I exit and re login via ssh, it does not. I mean the line ends after ```.....synced at```